# Cannot remove a row in DataGrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am getting the source for my DataGrid like so:

```
public void GetAllPlaza()
        {
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"/JsonData/Reader.json"))
            {
                var jsonString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                var rfid = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Reader>>(jsonString);
                var dataTable = Helpers.Helpers.ConvertToTable(rfid);
                DataGridReaders.ItemsSource = dataTable.AsDataView();
            }
        }
```

This is in my "XAML"

```
 <DataGrid
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    x:Name="DataGridReaders" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                    Height="Auto" 
                    Margin="10" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                    ColumnWidth="*" 
                    Width="Auto"
                    IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly}"
                    SelectionUnit="{Binding SelectionMode}" 
                    SelectionChanged="DataGridRfid_RowSelect"/>
```

Whenever I try to clear 1 row like this, I get an error:

```
DataGridReaders.Items.RemoveAt(DataGridReaders.SelectedIndex);
```

This is the error:

> 'Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.'

How can I fix this?

Comment: The error "DataGridReaders.ItemsSource" tells you to remove it from the table, not the grid.

Comment: How do i do it Sir?

Comment: Bind the data grid to a data source you can work with, you load a json from disk and then stick it in a var that you convert.... how will you save the data back to the json file after you removed the row...